# xampp on windows 7: set chmod

Tags: windows-7, xampp, concrete5

i am running xampp on my windows 7 machine. i've downloaded the sourcecode for concrete5 5.4.2.2 (that is a PHP-based CMS) but some directories are not writeable, see screenie:

[image: install screen]
since there is no such thing as chmod on windows i am now wondering how to make the folders writeable by the webserver?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps that should help you. First, check what user the web server is running as. If you can't see it easily, just Task Manager - it should show you. Then, once you know that user, give him read/write permissions through windows explorer to that folder. Alternatively, you could give "eveyone" access this way, but that has some serious security implications.

Comment: cool thanks this helped! i also had to add the folder "packages" manually to my concrete5 directory because it was not there.